# .htaccess - redirect a php File to an Virtual Directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory, virtual

What are the .htaccess lines to make a Virtual Directory from a PHP File?

`www.domain.de/file.php` should go to `www.domain.de/file/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^file/ file.php [L]
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1/ [L]
```

This will make it is if you enter http://www.domain.de/something/, the webserver will rewrite the URI to /something.php. You just need to make sure you serve your links as `/something/`

Comment: Thanks but thats not it.

This makes a Error with the index.php ofcourse.

I want redirect single php files. Can you help me?